# Can I change smart contract which is already deployed on BSC?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20

Everyone!
I have a token contract that has a mint function.
It has only burn function and it deployed to the mainnet.
I am going to add the mint function to the token.
It is available?
Here is the current token contract.
contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Burnable {

```
    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("MyToken", "MY", 18) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 15000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
}
```

Above contract used openzeppelin.
I will be very thankful if you teach me how to change this contract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a live smart contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573717/updating-a-live-smart-contract)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update it unless you have used a proxy or otherwise coded in that you can update it. You'll have to redeploy.

[Updating a live smart contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573717/updating-a-live-smart-contract)